# Как проверить наличие символов в regexp, но не захватывать их?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую.
Есть строка вида `mysite.com/somepage, mysite.com/anotherpage, ...`. Я хочу выбрать отсюда в массив только имена страниц, находящихся на сайте mysite.com, то есть `somepage` и `anotherpage`. Использую такое регулярное выражение:

```
/(?:mysite\.com)(?:\/\S*)?/
```

Как можно сделать проверку, что `mysite.com` стоит перед именем страницы, но не включать `mysite.com` в результат? Когда я делаю

```
preg_match_all("/(?:mysite\.com)(?:\/\S*)?/", $str, $res);
```

На выходе получаю массив вместе с доменом. Хотя, по идее, `?:` ведь должен исключать домен из результата. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` помимо групп захвата в круглых скобках возвращает еще и массив полного совпадения шаблона. По умолчанию в $res[0] содержится массив полных вхождений шаблона. Именно его вы и видите. Кроме него могут быть дополнительные массивы, если в выражении есть круглые скобки без `?:`.

Есть несколько решений:

1. Использовать выражение `mysite\.com(\/\S*)?`, не смотреть в $res[0], а только в $res[1] - где будут содержаться вхождения первой подмаски `(/\S*)`.
2. Использовать ограничитель `\K`. Если он встречается в выражении - то полным совпадением ($res[0]) считается все, что идет после него. То что стоит перед ним только проверяется на присутствие. Получаем `mysite\.com\K(?:\/\S*)?`
3. Использовать не захватывающую предварительную проверку `(?<=)`. все что заключено в нее только проверяется на наличие *перед* нужным нам утверждением.
   `(?<=mysite\.com)(?:\/\S*)?`

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь всё работает :)